# Passing a value from an input field to a php function in Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, wordpress-hook

When I select the category from the dropdown menu, it updates correctly in the input field. Ideally, it should update the recipe filter in recipeIndex.php.

I've tried wrapping the input in a form with method "get" but that still doesn't work.

The HTML is in an HTML widget on the Recipe Index page. The CSS, JavaScript and PHP code are in separate snippets (I used the Woody Snippets Wordpress plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-php/)

Please help.

HTML

```
<div class="dropdown_container">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="select">
          <span class="select_span">Select Category</span>
          <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
        </div>
        <form action="" method="get">  
        <input type="hidden" name="category" id="category">
        </form>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="recipeDropdown">
            <li id="All" name="All" value="All">All</li>
          <li id="Vegan" name="Vegan" value="Vegan">Vegan</li>
          <li id="Vegetarian" name="Vegetarian" value="Vegetarian">Vegetarian</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
```

CSS

```
    
.dropdown_container {
  width: 160px;
}

.select {
    width: 160px;
}

/*Styling Selectbox*/
.dropdown {
  width: 160px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgb(204, 204, 204);
  transition: all .5s ease;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #474747;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: left
}
.dropdown .select {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
}
.dropdown .select > i {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #888;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    float: right;
    line-height: 15px
}
.dropdown:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgb(204, 204, 204)
}
.dropdown:active {
    background-color: #f8f8f8
}
.dropdown.active:hover,
.dropdown.active {
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgb(204, 204, 204);
    border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
    background-color: #f8f8f8
}
.dropdown.active .select > i {
    transform: rotate(-90deg)
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: 1px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgb(204, 204, 204);
    border-radius: 0 1px 2px 2px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
    overflow-y: auto;
    z-index: 9
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu li {
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer
} 
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu li:hover {
    background-color: #f2f2f2
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu li:active {
    background-color: #e2e2e2
}
```

JavaScript

```
var $ = jQuery;

    $('.dropdown').click(function () {
        $(this).attr('tabindex', 1).focus();
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').slideToggle(300);
    });
    $('.dropdown').focusout(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').slideUp(300);
    });
    $('.dropdown .dropdown-menu li').click(function () {
        var value = $(this).attr("value");
        $("input[name='category']").val(value);
        $(this).parents('.dropdown').find('span').text($(this).text());
        $(this).parents('.dropdown').find('input').attr('value', $(this).attr('id'));
    });
```

PHP

```
// Posts or Portfolio Widget
add_action( 'elementor/query/recipe-index-filter', function( $query ) {
    // Modify the posts query here
    $category =  $_GET['category'];
    $query->set( 'category_name', $category );
} );
```

Comment: A form isn’t going to magically submit itself, just because you set the value of a hidden field.

Comment: Oh right. Sorry. The thing is I don't want a submit button. I want the user to just change the dropdown category and automatically update the query to filter by the selected category. I'm currently researching how to do this without a form, with ajax, but even that's not working so far. And Elementor publishing is not working at the moment, so I'm a bit stuck.

Comment: Forms can be submitted _via_ JavaScript, there’s a method for that. But this really doesn’t need a form to begin with, you might as well just assemble the desired target URL yourself, and then assign it to `location.href` to navigate there.

Comment: Do you want to change URL when dropdown changed?